# How to insert array data into database using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, ajax, database, codeigniter

How to insert array data into the database using ajax in CodeIgniter?
In my view I use code below, I have stack to find the solution because have many different structures

```
<form class="form-story" action=""  onsubmit="return false" id="form-story">
    <div class="tag-input form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-right">
                <label for="crew" class="control-label">Crew #1</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-5">
                <input type="text" name="crew_name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="NAME OF CREW MEMBER #1" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
                <input type="text" name="crew_email[]" class="form-control" placeholder="EMAIL OF CREW MEMBER #1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tag-input form-group">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-right">
               <label for="crew" class="control-label">Crew #2</label>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-5">
               <input type="text" name="crew_name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="NAME OF CREW MEMBER #2" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
               <input type="text" name="crew_email[]" class="form-control" placeholder="EMAIL OF CREW MEMBER #2">
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="tag-input form-group">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-right">
            <label for="crew" class="control-label">Crew #3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-5">
            <input type="text" name="crew_name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="NAME OF CREW MEMBER #3" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
            <input type="text" name="crew_email[]" class="form-control" placeholder="EMAIL OF CREW MEMBER #3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="btn-add-more-wrapper" class="form-group text-center btn-add-more-wrapper">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btn-add-more">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <br> Add More
    </a>
</div>
<div class="btn-groups-wrapper">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" onClick="" value="SUBMIT" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default is-disabled">
    </div>
</div>
</form>

<script>
    $('#form-story').submit(function() {
        var dataString = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url  : '<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/the_flow_crew/save_tag_member',
            data : dataString,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(res) {
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Please help me to give the solution,  Thank you

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your post data into jsonencode and try to store in database. It will work.

For example

```
$crew_name = json_encode($_POST['crew_name']);
```

Above code will convert your array into json string. When you try to retrieve the data back in array format try to use `json_decode($column_name)` it help you to sort out your problem

If you want to store entire post into database pass your $_POST in `json_encode($_POST)`

Let me know if you need more guidelines on it. I'm happy to help you out.